# How can I reference a font in a static resource from a community login page when I can't use URLFOR in CSS and the static resource sits behind auth?

Tags: css, force.com-sites, experience-cloud

Working on rebranding a portal/community/experience login page.  The designers, being non-Salesforce folk, have a CSS font-face tag in there that references the font files and I've got them in a static resource now (zipped, no subfolders, resource called `fonts`

The problem is that I can't seem to use the static resources because they sit on the other side of the auth mechanism, therefore they get redirected to the login page, the HTML gets served back into where it's expecting a font and of course that breaks.

I've tried a couple of approaches so far

```
url(({!URLFOR($Resource.fonts,'/franklingothicurw-boo.woff')})
```

which gives a 404 not found

and

```
url(/esg/s/sfsites/c/resource/fonts/franklingothicurw-boo.woff)
```

which redirects to the login page and gives `OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 218774561`

Is there a way to reference the fonts correctly in a CSS `font-face` tag prior to site authentication?

If it makes a difference, these are *old* style pages, using Force.com/Visualforce tech.  No Lightning here I'm afraid

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn’t set visibility to Public on the static resources that you need accessible from the public login.

Comment: Rob- If you are referencing a Zip file then your relative path must start with `fonts/font...` like this `url(({!URLFOR($Resource.fonts,'fonts/franklingothicurw-boo.woff')})`. The relative path must include full hierarchy of sub-folder structure and not just the `.woff` file only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems to be fixed now.  The URLFOR approach appears to work, but I ended up with the font resources as a static resource each in their own right, not zipped, and referenced them individually

```
url({!URLFOR($Resource.franklingothicurw_boo_woff2))
```

Comment: I get fonts from the zipped static resource. However, I faced one potential bug - when I reference some fonts, I'm getting ERR_ABORTED 404. I don't know if this is due to the size of the archive or number of the files. But when I removed some of the files, that I don't use, the issue disappeared.